# android textview not supporting symbols

Tags: android, string, textview

```
<string name="feat"> * Good User Interface \n * Fast Searching \n * Text To Speech \n * Simple Interface & Offline \n * Low Memory Usage \n * Favourites option \n * Login Option \n * Social Network Link \n * Sharing Application Option </string>
```

this is the statement got error.
The error is "The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.'

Comment: I am guessing, replace `&` with `&amp;` and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Use `&amp;` in place of `&` symbol.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your XML datasource contains '&' character in some data.

If so replace '&' with `&amp;` and try, it should work properly.

In Additional to it, Some of other Common in xml how to escape the errors:

- ampersand (&) is escaped to &
- double quotes (") are escaped to "
- single quotes (') are escaped to '
- less than (<) is escaped to . <
- greater than (>) is escaped to . >

Answer (score 1):

While the above solutions will work Another good solution can be to enclose your string resource in **CDATA** tag like:

```
<string name="feat"><![CDATA[ * Good User Interface \n * Fast Searching \n * Text To Speech \n * Simple Interface & Offline \n * Low Memory Usage \n * Favourites option \n * Login Option \n * Social Network Link \n * Sharing Application Option ]]></string>
```

This way it will be easy as you won't have to replace each and every & with `&amp;` which is tedious task.This may work with all special characters i guess(not tested).

Comment: I will up vote it as a sportsmanship, bcz it vll also works along with my answer !!